# How to select current number of the day of week?

Tags: r

How can I select current number of the day of week?

For example today it's Tuesday, i.e. 2nd day, so the expected output is "2".

This code return name

```
weekdays(Sys.Date())
```

But I need a number.

Comment: `as.POSIXlt(Sys.Date())$wday`

Answer (score 2):

From `lubridate` you can use the `wday` function:

```
library(lubridate)
wday(Sys.Date())
[1] 3
```

Note that in this function Sunday is the first day of the week, so the number for Tuesday is `3`.